# jQuery - draggable images on iPad / iPhone - how to integrate event.preventDefault();?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, multi-touch, jquery-mobile

I use jQuery, jQuery UI and jQuery mobile to build a web application for iPhone / iPad.
Now I create images and they should be draggable, so I did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Drag - Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div>
        <div style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid red;">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/9e/JQuery_logo.svg/200px-JQuery_logo.svg.png" class="draggable" alt="jQuery logo" />
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ab/Apple-logo.png" class="draggable" alt="Apple Inc. logo" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Here you can see the live example: http://jsbin.com/igena4/

The problem is, that the whole page want to scroll. I searched in Apple's HTML5 examples and found this to prevent the scrolling of the page, so that the image is draggable:

```
...
onDragStart: function(event) {
    // stop page from panning on iPhone/iPad - we're moving a note, not the page
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

But the problem is for me, how can I include this into my jQuery? Where do I get `event`?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this library

https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch

> Just follow these simple steps to enable touch events in your jQuery
>   UI app:
>
> 1. Include jQuery and jQuery UI on your page.
>
>    ```
>    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
>    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
>    ```
> 2. Include Touch Punch after jQuery UI and before its first use.
>
>    Please note that if you are using jQuery UI's components, Touch Punch must be included after jquery.ui.mouse.js, as Touch Punch
>      modifies its behavior.
>
>    ```
>    <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
>    ```
> 3. There is no 3. Just use jQuery UI as expected and watch it work at the touch of a finger.
>
>    ```
>    <script>$('#widget').draggable();</script>
>    ```

Comment: +1 for mentioning this, I have worked a lot with this and works great with jquery ui.

Comment: This is so cool. It just works! Just tested on Opera Mobile, Firefox/Fennec and Nokia N9 default browser. Of those 3 only Fennec is a bit clunky (but still works). See example here:
http://m.enux.pl/_tests/jui/demos/droppable/photo-manager.html

Comment: make sure to <script> this after you <script> jquery-ui in the head or it won't work...like any other dependant <script> declarations

Comment: +1 for touchpunch! You just include the library and it works (for draggability is the only thing i tested though).

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution which is working on Desktop browser and iOS Safari on iPad and iPhone: 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

You only have to download and integrate the JavaScript file, that's it.

Comment: Would be nice to find what exactly is the fix, because it's surely applied there.

Comment: I think it is done with several preventDefaults. I did not take a deeper look inside the code, first I am happy it is working :-)

Comment: Wow I knew your not the first to have this problem :)

Comment: I took a look at the code and it is simply brilliant. They added listners to events that are particular to iOS such as touchstart, touchmove, touchend and map it to jQuery events such as click, dlbClick, drag and so on... jQuery's event model makes it real easy to "map" new events to old ones ! Their code is nicely written and with comments. You should take a look at it. Not just a couple of preventDefaults ;) If your are building a custom app just for iOs, I would recommend usign the right events.

Comment: But what I do no know yet, is how can realize that two or more elements are draggable simultaneously. I have 10 fingers, but I can only use one to drag and drop.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it'd look like this

```
$(document).bind("dragstart", function(event, ui){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  //return false;//edited
  });
```

I'm not sure if it should be `document` or just `'body'`

**EDIT**

I don't know where you took that code sample from, but it seems to always block any dragging. Try if this helps - it should prevent bubbling up, so if scrolling works with the document node - the event shouldn't get there. [I still can't try it on apples]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".draggable").draggable();
        $('body>div').bind("dragstart", function(event, ui){
        event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Both does not work, see http://jsbin.com/igena4/2/ and http://jsbin.com/igena4/3/ I does not work in iPad and I can not drag in a normal webbrowser with the mouse anymore.

Comment: Ok. Can you link to the place you found the info that you should bind preventDefault to onDragStart? You might need to bind it to a specific thing, or it was misleading. I don't have a touchscreen device, so I can't get to it with trial and error.

Comment: try without `return false`. I think it was too much.

Comment: Also without `return false` it does not work. Exactly same behavior: http://jsbin.com/igena4/5/ - http://jsbin.com/igena4/6/ Can not drag with the mouse and not draggable with the finger.

Comment: I ask again - where did you find the fragment with onDragStart?

Comment: I took it from this example: http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/StickyNotes/ and the JS file: http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/StickyNotes/resources/notes.js

Comment: As you can see in the code you linked to - every drag-related event handler returns false and all except drag prevent their defaults. You would have to bind to some more events and/or change the draggable implementation a bit. I'd do it for you just for the fun of it if somebody gave me an iPad to play with. Or you can post a link to an emulator for linux that would let me reproduce it, and I will get to it in January. No kidding.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not simulator / emulator which have this problem. All simulators like http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/ or web pages like http://ipadpeek.com/ take of course the mouse as the tap-drag, and so there it works.

Comment: I will be disconnected since tomorrow upto 03.01.11 but after that we could have a remote cooperation session of coding a working example and testing(done by you) with chat feedback. Unless you get to it yourself earlier of course ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found a solution: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Answer (score 3):

jQuery 1.9 will do this for you.

Here's a link to the RC: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/08/jquery-ui-1-9-rc/

Comment: Would be nice if that file still existed D:

Comment: you can try out the jquery 1.9 beta here now: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/06/jquery-ui-1-9-beta/

Comment: Touch is *not* part of jQuery UI 1.9

Answer (score 0):

You should simply go look at jquery's Doc http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events

You callback for the start event should be hook when you call the draggable method, as with every other jQuery, there is always a param where you can pass an objects which contains the callbacks. Try calling preventDefaut in the start callback.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        start: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            counts[ 0 ]++;
            updateCounterStatus( $start_counter, counts[ 0 ] );
        },
        drag: function() {
            counts[ 1 ]++;
            updateCounterStatus( $drag_counter, counts[ 1 ] );
        },
        stop: function() {
            counts[ 2 ]++;
            updateCounterStatus( $stop_counter, counts[ 2 ] );
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already did this in this way: `start: function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }` but then nothing works - no mouse drag, no finger drag.

Comment: It looks like it's the way to do this with jqueryUI, you just have to fiddle with this. Add more `preventDefault`s here and there, try to stop bubbling on different events...

Comment: Did you try holding the Ipad scroll with one finger and draging with another finger (other hand) ? I use this trick often on website that has a scrolling div....

Comment: This does not work, but I found a solution, see my answer post.