# jQuery Mobile - Safari browser sliding around screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, mobile, safari

I am just finishing off a mobile web application for a client. I have written it using MVC3 and Razor and using jQuery Mobile. Something I hadn't noticed but the client has is that Safari (and only Safari) seems to be able to move around the screen when using the web application. Difficult to explain here but you can slide the whole browser to the left, right, up and down leaving a Grey background behind it, this is not something that other mobile sites do. 
 Does anyone have an idea of what this might be? I don't even know where to start with it!
 Thanks in advance to all who contribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for anyone who comes across this I have found the solution. The css that comes with the jquery mobile framework contains the class ui-body-c (with the c being replaced by other letters dependiong on theme). In this class there is a border: 1px solid #ccc;, removing this has removed the issue without changing any styling on the site.

Comment: our client also reported same issue and I can see that too. I am not using jquery mobile and body doesn't have border. Any idea how to fix in that case?

Comment: fixed: header had width 96% + padding. just removed padding from left and right and centered it with margin auto instead. that fixed the issue. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it has to do with the issue described in this question: [jQuery - draggable images on iPad / iPhone - how to integrate event.preventDefault();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488601/jquery-draggable-images-on-ipad-iphone-how-to-integrate-event-preventdefaul/4488662#4488662)

Comment: I tried adding this $(document).bind("dragstart", function(event, ui){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  //return false; }); But it has made no difference, tried with the return false included as well, but still nothing....

Comment: The result of the thread I mentioned was that adding a library prepped for apple stuff helped. If I were you I would start with that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately this hasn't made a difference, it either stops all movements of the screen or with the modifications recommended makes no change at all. I guess I'm going to struggle to find an answer for this. Its the same behavior that happens on every site when you pinch/zoom in, but mine seems to do it when you don't zoom.

Comment: I think it just happens when a site doesn't fit in the window (is too big at the moment). Using the jqueryUi for apple helps. It's in that topic there, in the last comment. You overseen it. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/