# jquery mobile drag and drop

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm playing around with the drag and drop feature of jQuery UI and it's working on my website, but when I navigate to my web page on an iPad, then the divs don't drag - the page itself moves up and down.

I've have in the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://forresst.github.com/2012/06/22/Make-a-list-jQuery-Mobile-sortable-by-drag-and-drop/

Comment: What did you end up doing? Did you check out any of the libraries suggested to you? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - draggable images on iPad / iPhone - how to integrate event.preventDefault();?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488601/jquery-draggable-images-on-ipad-iphone-how-to-integrate-event-preventdefau)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Excellent sample solutions](http://furf.com/exp/touch-punch/index.html):

> #### jQuery UI Touch Punch is a small hack that enables the use of touch events on sites using the jQuery UI user interface library.
>
> Currently, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) user interface library does not support the use of touch events in their widgets and interactions. This means that the slick UI you designed and tested in your desktop browser will fail on most, if not all, touch-enabled mobile devices, becuase jQuery UI listens to mouse events—mouseover, mousemove and mouseout—not touch events—touchstart, touchmove and touchend.
>
> That's where jQuery UI Touch Punch comes in. Touch Punch works by using [simulated events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) to map [touch events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/) to their mouse event analogs. Simply include the script on your page and your touch events will be turned into their corresponding mouse events to which jQuery UI will respond as expected.
>
> As I said, Touch Punch is a hack. It [duck punches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) some of jQuery UI's core functionality to handle the mapping of touch events...

Comment: this is for jquery-UI ... ... but does it work with jquery-mobile?

Comment: declare touch-punch after jquery-ui in the head of your html file or it won't work

Answer (score 18):

This problem is known and has already been investigated.

It requires a correct `.preventDefault()` call in the right event handler.

Everything you need is here:

[jQuery - draggable images on iPad / iPhone - how to integrate event.preventDefault();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488601/jquery-draggable-images-on-ipad-iphone-how-to-integrate-event-preventdefaul/4488662#4488662)

Answer (score 13):

http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/ contains an excellent code sniplet that converts touch events to mouse events:

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

    switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }

    // initMouseEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, view, clickCount,
    //                screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey,
    //                altKey, shiftKey, metaKey, button, relatedTarget);

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                              first.screenX, first.screenY,
                              first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                              false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function init()
{
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
```

Comment: great answer; posted a cleaned up gist here: https://gist.github.com/pxwise/cf35323237db7995103e

Answer (score 4):

Hammer.js provides a powerful dragging feature. https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js