# How to get jquery dragging working on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an application where I allow users to drag some images around. It uses jquery. I'm trying to get it working on mobile devices (on the iPhone, if I drag the image then it drags the whole page). I want to use jquery mobile. Is this right way to go? If so, is it pretty easy to transition from regular jquery to jquery mobile? And also, if I use jquery mobile, will it still be draggable from a desktop as well?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile drag and drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345762/jquery-mobile-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a very simple solution to this problem - [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).

It works by effectively converting touch events into click events, so your draggable code will work as you'd hoped on mobile/tablet touch screens.

To implement, you just need to download the Touch Punch script and then include it in your HTML ***after*** your other jQuery / jQuery UI includes:

`<script src="scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>`

I have tested on Android and iOS and it worked first time for me with no issues at all.

Comment: It's not working for me with Chrome on Android mobile. any possible solution ?

Comment: Sorry, @NeosFox, only just seen your comment. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Oops !!! the comment was about 2 years ago, I can't recall that problem, may be I solved that :D will update here, if I got any recall.

Comment: Not the best solution: if the element to drag takes the whole viewport, using jQuery UI Touch Punch prevents the document to be scrolled. Can be even a problem with element you want to be only draggable horizontally with a container hiding overflow, as a draggable carousel. In this case, the carousel prevents user to scroll the document up and down.
I prefer jQuery Touch (github.com/ajlkn/jquery.touch) which makes draggable possibly touch only on mobile (mouse gesture can be filtered) and does not prevent touch events to propagate (thus, document to be scrolled).

Comment: @ban-geoengineering The link leads to a 404?

Comment: Bit late, but here you go: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/find/master