# Jquery Drag and Drop Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios

I am having a problem with bringing Jquery over to iPad. I made a drag and drop puzzle using Jquery, and on my computer it works fine. When I try to move that over to the iPad, the drag and drop functions cease to work. I have tried many a third party fix for this problem with no avail. Does anyone know how to solve this problem on iOS5? Or is there a better way to code it in HTML5 that works or a Jquery solution I do not know of? Any tutorials on the issue would be appreciated as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery Mobile instead, and make sure you use `.preventDefault()` as mentioned in this post:

[jquery mobile drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5345762/362536)

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488662/362536

Comment: how does that work? So after every event handler I have, I just put .preventDefault() ???

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html