# Javascript Scrollbar on Mobile Devices Workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm building a draggable timeline of sorts for a new project using some simple jquery ui features and have run into a problem regarding mobile devices.

Namely, drag and drop just doesn't work on touch screen devices like that.  I've noticed any video players you pull up run proprietary plugins on your phone so moving the timeline around is not an issue. But, seeing as I'm not really doing video, I was hoping for some sort of work around.

Thoughts?

Comment: Something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488601/jquery-draggable-images-on-ipad-iphone-how-to-integrate-event-preventdefaul may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [JQuery Mobile Drag and Drop](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mobiledraganddrop)

See [here](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Jquery-Mobile-Drag-And-Drop/) for some documentation.

**NOTE** Using JQuery mobile will work on some phones, but not all phones. Older Blackberries, HTC Phones, and many other ones cannot handle many JQuery Mobile calls. Look [at this page](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) for more information on compatability