# Breaking swipeleft/-right when drag an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have got a problem with the swipe event and dragging an element.

In my application I use swipeleft/-right to navigate between the pages (it works). 
In one page there are a lot of dragging elements (drag works).

So the problem is, when an element is dragging horizontal to the right, the swipeleft works after dragstop. It's the same with dragging to the left, swiperight works.

It makes me confused.

So is it possible to stop or break the swipeleft/-right when I drag an element?

This is the code for swipe (from Stackoverflow thx)

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function() {
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, 'slide');
    }
});
$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function() {
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, 'slide', true);
    }
});
```

And this is the code for drag

```
$ (function(){
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];    
    numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );
    alert(numbers);

for ( var i=1; i<6; i++ ) {
    $('#'+i).attr( 'src','bilder/'+numbers[i-1]+'.png' ).draggable( {
      cursor: 'move',
      containment: $('#'+i).parent().parent(),
      revert: true,

    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: set a flag on/off drag, and then check for the flag in your swipe function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now I got the solution:

o.v.'s answer was correct and with ahren's tip I've solved it.

To explain here is the code:

```
var moveme=false;  // global variable is false(by default) when no element is dragged

$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function (event){

if(moveme===true){event.preventDefault(); return false;}

var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
// swipe using id of next page if exists

if (nextpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(nextpage, 'slide',true);
}
});

$('div.ui-page').live("swiperight", function(event){

if(moveme===true){event.preventDefault(); return false;}

var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
// swipe using id of next page if exists

if ( prevpage.length > 0) {
$.mobile.changePage(prevpage, 'slide', true);
}
});
```

The draggable-code:

```
$ (function(){
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];    
    numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );
    alert(numbers);

for ( var i=1; i<6; i++ ) {
    $('#'+i).attr( 'src','bilder/'+numbers[i-1]+'.png' ).draggable( {
      cursor: 'move',
      containment: $('#'+i).parent().parent(),
      revert: true,



      start: function(){moveme=true;}, //if an element is dragged moveme=true and
                                       //event.preventDefault() is used. So it is not possible to swipe
      stop: function(){moveme=false;}, //after dragging swipe can be used (default)

        });

  } 
});
```

So, thank you very much for your help o.v. and ahren

Answer (score 3):

jQuery [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) should handle exactly that. In your current code, upon completion of the drag event handler, the gesture would "continue" to be parsed by the mobile browser - and if a user drag-and-drop action resembles a left-swipe, it would trigger the relevant handler:

```
$('div.ui-page').live("swipeleft", function(_event) { //reference the event object
  /*your code*/
  _event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

After the change, jQuery will instruct the browser that the event is done with and should not be "handed back" to the browser for triggering a default response (in your case, resolving a swipe gesture).

***Update:***

As mentioned in the comments, I've mistakenly suggested to `preventDefault()` as part of the swipe handler. This should have been part of *dragdrop* event handler. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4584804/1081234) recommending [this JS](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/) to be integrated - that should address your issue on a global level.

Comment: Thx for your anwer but it doesn't work. It's the same problem like before.

Comment: @nilevee: I now realise that `event.preventDefault()` should have been  part of the *dragdrop* event handler, not the other way around - I'll have another look at it

Comment: Can you tell me how to realise your idea, please?  One hour ago I've got an idea but it doesn't work.