# jQuery scrollable/draggable div on mobile

Tags: jquery

How to do a scrollable/draggable div for mobile? I'm trying to do it without any plugins.

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a containing div that is the width of the viewport with overflow hidden and a nested div that is wider that allows you to drag the nested div left and right.

Comment: The Link below should have some good suggestions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488601/jquery-draggable-images-on-ipad-iphone-how-to-integrate-event-preventdefau

Comment: So far, what you have achieved in making one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to over engineer this to death I realize I should just set the containing div to `overflow: scroll` in CSS to achieve exactly what I wanted to do.